# Creating sentences by a function without using a package

Tags: python, list, sentence

Im currently writing a program that looks at a list and iterates through a groups the words into sentences but whenever i ran it, I got [] and im not 100% sure why. Here is my code for reading in the file, and creating the sentence and an attached snippet of the list.

```
def import_file(text_file):
    wordcounts = []
    with open(text_file, encoding = "utf-8") as f:
        pride_text = f.read()
        sentences = pride_text.split(" ")
        return sentences





def create_sentance(sentance):
    sentence_list=[]
    my_sentence=""
    for character in sentance:
        if character=='.' or character=='?' or character=='!':
            sentence_list.append(my_sentence) 
            my_sentence=""
        else:
            my_sentence=my_sentence + character
        return sentence_list
```

[Preview of List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DRFV.png)
Calling of my functions

```
pride=import_file("pride.txt")
pride=remove_abbreviations_and_punctuation(pride)
pride=create_sentance(pride)
print(pride)
```

Comment: Can you include an example of how you call `create_sentance`? (It's spelled sentence, by the way).

Comment: i realized that after i wrote it :P. I included in the code above how i call it

Comment: Sidenote: you might want to check out the `nltk` package -- Natural Language Toolkit. It could help with what you're doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `return sentence_list` is indented one further than it should be. After the first iteration of the `for`, should the `else` condition execute and not the `if`, then your function returns `sentence_list` which was initialized to `[ ]`. Either way, if `sentence` was 20 characters long, your `for` will only run once given where your `return` call is.

Make the following change:

```
def create_sentance(sentance):
    sentence_list=[]
    my_sentence=""

    for character in sentance:
        if character=='.' or character=='?' or character=='!':
            sentence_list.append(my_sentence) 
            my_sentence=""
        else:
            # do you not want this in 'sentence_list'?
            my_sentence=my_sentence + character 
    return sentence_list
```

Comment: I dont want anything done to sentence_list in the else because I am just trying to add words together until there is a . ? or ! reached.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your function is returning an empty list is because your return is inside the for loop. In addition, "character" is actually a word, since each element of your list is a word. This program works:

```
def create_sentance(sentance):
    sentence_list=[]
    my_sentence=""
    for character in sentance:
        print character
        if '.' in character or '?' in character or '!' in character:
            sentence_list.append(my_sentence + ' ' + character)
            my_sentence=""
        else:
            my_sentence=my_sentence + ' ' + character
    return sentence_list
create_sentance(['I','will','go','to','the','park.','Ok?'])
```

You need to use "in" instead of == because each character is a word. Try printing "character" to see this. The above program works and returns the result

```
[' I will go to the park.', 'Ok?']
```

which is what you were intending.

Comment: pstatix's answer is not accurate because it will not return the correct list, since the 'in' command is not used.